# Why scanf() in C ignores any leading whitespaces but terminates reading a string when it encounters any trailing spaces?

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
char str[20];
scanf("%s", str);
printf("%s", str);
```

**Input 1**
-->  Hi
prints -->Hi(Even though I added some spaces before 'Hi')

**Input 2**
-->Hello World
prints -->Hello(scanf terminates reading char after it encounters any whitespaces but in Input 1 it didnt act as a terminating point but was just truncated.)

Comment: Because that's what the language definition specifies. Why does the language definition specify such a thing? Because it's the most natural and useful thing to do in most cases. "but in Input 1 it didnt act as a terminating point but was just truncated" How can you tell one from the other?

Comment: It doesn't always ignore leading whitespace. Specifiers `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not, but adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too.

Comment: When `scanf` is reading for `%s` and sees a space, it must continue reading to get to the string to be read. Then it reads the string, which consists of non-white-space characters. Then when it sees a space, it is done reading the string, so it stops (and “puts back” the space). So the reason `scanf` skips leading spaces but leaves trailing spaces is simple logic: You must skip leading spaces to get to the string, and trailing spaces indicate you are done.